# HTML table with colspan is displayed wrong

Tags: html, css

I've created a table, **in which all headers have colspan=2**, and some body cells have colspan=N.

The display breaks in some cases:

[image: screenshot]

```css
td, th {
  border: solid #aaa 1px
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th colspan="2" scope="col">8 AM</th>
      <th colspan="2" scope="col">9 AM</th>
      <th colspan="2" scope="col">10 AM</th>
      <th colspan="2" scope="col">11 AM</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>

      <td colspan="5"><span>-</span></td>

      <td><a href="#">+</a></td>
      <td><a href="#">+</a></td>
      <td><a href="#">+</a></td>

    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Pay attention to the "-" cell, which should stretch to the center of the "10 AM" column, but does not.

What could be the cause?

Comment: But the total count of columns of thead is not equal to tbody's columns.

Comment: you dont give any colspan to table headers.
https://jsfiddle.net/0sL4hwar/

Comment: Of course it breaks. You have colspan 5, It should be 4 because the headers above are 2+2.

Comment: The head is 2+2+2+2=8. And I want the body to have 5+1+1+1=8.
What's wrong with my math?

Comment: Nothing is wrong with your math. It is the table rendering model that is catching you out. By default tables are rendered with a minimal cell width. The 5th cell in a row effectively has no content and therefore minimal width. See what happens when you add content to the 5th cell : http://jsfiddle.net/3dLscg4o/1/

Comment: So my only choice is to add another row with `visibility:hidden`?

Answer (score -2):

i think you have want some thing like this!

```
<tbody>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="4"><span>-</span></td>
      <td><a href="#">+</a></td>
      <td><a href="#">+</a></td>
      <td><a href="#">+</a></td>
      <td><a href="#">+</a></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
```